# Fleshing out the stochiometric/molar quantities

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Any help appreciated, it's been 37 yrs. since I was in univ. chemistry class.

Trying to flesh out the stochiometric/molar quantities (grams) of magnesium oxide to be combined with monoammoniumphosphate (MAP, a common fertilizer) to create ammonium magnesium phosphate x 6 H2O ?

MAP (NH4H2PO4) is an acidic dihydrogen compound, MO is an alkaline oxide, so it appears at 1:1 mix ratio I already have a problem of excess protons - -  not enough hydroxyls.

I'm guessing I can simply heat it the combination in distilled H2O on a magnetic stirrer overnight, then try cooling it to separate by crystals , but I have read that AMP is sparingly soluble in water, so maybe just push pH slightly above 7, cool in fridge, decant and harvest the "sludge" or crystals ?
Combining the two should ultimately yield H2O as the byproduct, plus I have excess protons.

This substance is a common problem in sewage treatment plants where it precipitates on pipes, as well as kidney stones in humans and dogs.